# Do I miss something by using MySQL without stored procedures?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

At work I use .NET with SQL Server, but for my personal projects  I always rely on shared Linux hosting (most are quite tiny websites just presenting content and some outdate my .NET work).

Right now I'm facing this problem: one of my personal projects (in PHP) won't make it without a database. I started developing (using Wamp on my desktop and Xampp on my laptop) but now that I try to do some live tests, I realise that most shared hosts disable many functionalities of MySQL databases, including stored procedures and if I want to use them, I will have to learn how to set a Linux server.

Add to this that my project has so to say no budget but I would feel OK if I put like 100 EUR/year in it, I don't want it to take forever before it's online and I don't to spend another full time job maintaining it.

So one of my options right now is to recode without MySQL stored procedures, by the way I use prepared statements. Would I be missing something important regarding: Security? Performance? Scalability? Maintenance?

One of my thoughts is that I happens to install some CMS, phpBB etc. on shared hosting and never paid attention to the fact that it could not use stored procedures so it probably "standard" in MySQL world not to use stored procedures.

Comment: Stored procedures are relatively new to MySQL, so software like WordPress has done without them. I expect shared hosts that don't offer this feature are just on an old version of MySQL, rather than that they have disabled the feature. Just find a shared host with a recent version of MySQL and you should be fine (although it looks like [they were supported in 5.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html)).

Comment: Actually they are shared host with nearly newest versions of MySql. The reason why they disable stored procedures is that if you stored procedure starts for example an inifinite loop they say they have no control over it and cannot identify it.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't know they could be separated disabled - fair enough. Maybe find some shared hosts that will enable it for you? Once they are happy you know what you are doing with them, they may be OK.

Answer (score 2):

I've used MySql in combination with php for 6 years in professional environments and never used stored procedures. In my opinion the database should not contain any logic, it makes working with data harder when "strange" things are happening on the database. The logic should be in the php code.